# MPI_Allreduce not working as expected - Red Black SOR

Tags: c, mpi

I'm implementing a parallel version of Red Black SOR.

The MPI_Allreduce part, where I want to get the maximum error of every process, is not working. It never changes, it gives values higher than 2.0, even with only one process. What's going on??

Here's the code, the interesting part is at the end of the sor routine.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <math.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <mpi.h>

#define M 700

int numtasks, rank, inext, iprev, ista, iend;

double unew[M + 2][M + 2] = {{ 0 }};
double solution[M + 2][M + 2] = {{ 0 }};

double uold[M + 2][M + 2] = {{ 0 }};

double bufs1[M + 2];
double bufs2[M + 2];

double bufr1[M + 2];
double bufr2[M + 2];

MPI_Request ireqs1;
MPI_Request ireqs2;

MPI_Request ireqr1;
MPI_Request ireqr2;

MPI_Status istatus;

double compute_error(double solution[][M + 2], double u[][M + 2], const int m);
int sor(double unew[][M + 2], double uold[][M + 2], double solution[][M + 2], const double omega, const double tol, const int m);
void para_range(const int n1, const int n2, const int nprocs, const int irank, int * restrict ista, int * restrict iend);
void shift(const int iflg);
inline int min(const int a, const int b);

int main(int argc, char * argv[])
{
    const int m = M;

    int ierr = MPI_Init(&argc, &argv);

    if(ierr != MPI_SUCCESS)
    {
        perror("MPI init failed. Terminating T800.\n");
        exit(1);
    }

    int i, j;

    const double begin = MPI_Wtime();

    const double pi = 4.0 * atan(1.0);

    const double h = pi / (m + 1);

    MPI_Comm_size(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &numtasks);
    MPI_Comm_rank(MPI_COMM_WORLD, &rank);

    for(i = 0; i < m + 2; ++i)
    {
       uold[i][M + 1] = sin(i * h);
    }

    for(i = 0; i < m + 2; ++i)
    {
    for(j = 0; j < m + 1; ++j)
        {
            uold[i][j] = j * h * uold[i][M + 1];
        }
    }

    for(i = 0; i < m + 2; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 0; j < m + 2; ++j)
        {
            solution[i][j] = sinh(j * h) * sin(i * h) / sinh(pi);
        }
    }

    para_range(0, m, numtasks, rank, &ista, &iend);

    //printf("rank %d: from %d to %d\n", rank, ista, iend);

    inext = rank + 1;
    iprev = rank - 1;

    if(inext == numtasks)
    {
        inext = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }

    if(iprev == -1)
    {
        iprev = MPI_PROC_NULL;
    }

    const double omega = 2.0 / ( 1.0 + sin(pi / (m + 1)) );
    const double tol = 0.001;

    const int iters = sor(unew, uold, solution, omega, tol, m);

    const double end = MPI_Wtime();

    MPI_Finalize();

    if(rank == 0)
    {
        printf(" \n");
        printf(" Omega = %f\n", omega);
        printf(" It took %d iterations.\n", iters);

        printf("Total time = %f\n\n\n", end - begin);
    }

    return 0;
}

double compute_error(double solution[][M + 2], double u[][M + 2], const int m)
{
    double error = 0.0;
    int i, j;

    for(i = 1; i < m + 1; ++i)
    {
        for(j = 1; j < m + 1; ++j)
        {
            const double abs_diff = fabs(solution[i][j] - u[i][j]);

            if(error < abs_diff)
            {
                error = abs_diff;
            }
        }
    }

    return error;
}

int sor(double unew[][M + 2], double uold[][M + 2], double solution[][M + 2], const double omega, const double tol, const int m)
{
    int i, j;

    int iters = 0;
    double error = compute_error(solution, uold, m);
    double error2 = error;
    double temp;

    while(error2 > tol)
    {
        shift(0);

        for(i = 1; i < m + 1; ++i)
        {
            for(j = (i % 2) + 1; j < m + 1; j += 2)
            {
                temp = 0.25 * (uold[i][j - 1] + uold[i - 1][j]
                   + uold[i + 1][j] + uold[i][j + 1]) - uold[i][j];
                uold[i][j] += omega * temp;
            }
        }

        shift(1);

        for(i = 1; i < m + 1; ++i)
        {
            for(j = ((i + 1) % 2) + 1; j < m + 1; j += 2)
            {
                temp = 0.25 * (uold[i][j - 1] + uold[i - 1][j]
                   + uold[i + 1][j] + uold[i][j + 1]) - uold[i][j];
                uold[i][j] += omega * temp;
            }
        }

        ++iters;

        if(iters % 20 == 0)
        {
            // THIS IS NOT COOL
            error = compute_error(solution, uold, m);
            MPI_Allreduce(&error, &error2, 1, MPI_REAL, MPI_MAX, MPI_COMM_WORLD);

            //printf("%d=%f\n", rank, error2);
        }
    }

    return iters;
}

void para_range(const int n1, const int n2, const int nprocs, const int irank, int * restrict ista, int * restrict iend)
{
    const int iwork = ((n2 - n1) / nprocs) + 1;

    *ista = min(irank * iwork + n1, n2 + 1);
    *iend = min(*ista + iwork - 1, n2);
}

void shift(const int iflg)
{
    const int is1 = ((ista + iflg) % 2) + 1;
    const int is2 = ((iend + iflg) % 2) + 1;

    const int ir1 = 3 - is1;
    const int ir2 = 3 - is2;

    int i, icnt1=0, icnt2=0;

    if(rank != 0)
    {
        icnt1 = 0;

        for(i = is1; i < M; i += 2)
        {
            ++icnt1;
            bufs1[icnt1] = unew[i][ista];
        }
    }

    if (rank != numtasks - 1)
    {
        icnt2 = 0;

        for(i = is2; i < M; i += 2)
        {
            ++icnt2;
            bufs2[icnt2] = unew[i][iend];
        }
    }

    MPI_Isend(bufs1, icnt1, MPI_REAL, iprev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqs1);
    MPI_Isend(bufs2, icnt2, MPI_REAL, inext, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqs2);

    MPI_Irecv(bufr1, M + 2, MPI_REAL, iprev, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqr1);
    MPI_Irecv(bufr2, M + 2, MPI_REAL, inext, 1, MPI_COMM_WORLD, &ireqr2);

    MPI_Wait(&ireqs1, &istatus);
    MPI_Wait(&ireqs2, &istatus);

    MPI_Wait(&ireqr1, &istatus);
    MPI_Wait(&ireqr2, &istatus);

    int icnt;

    if(rank != 0)
    {
        icnt = 0;

        for(i = ir1; i < M; i += 2)
        {
            ++icnt;
            unew[i][ista - 1] = bufr1[icnt];
        }
    }

    if(rank != numtasks - 1)
        {
        icnt = 0;

        for(i = ir2; i < M; i += 2)
        {
            ++icnt;
            unew[i][iend + 1] = bufr2[icnt];
        }
    }
}

inline int min(const int a, const int b)
{
    if(a > b)
    {
        return b;
    }

    return a;
}
```

Comment: Although your error is easy to spot, this is by no way the kind of question that is well accepted here. Pasting a huge source code instead of the shortest possible minimal working example is no cool.

Comment: @HristoIliev I clarified that where the interesting part is. I understand the what you're telling me very well, I've been there too, but I was unaware if anything else could have affected this function call. I'll try my best to avoid this in the future!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

`MPI_REAL` is for Fortran's `REAL` type that usually corresponds to `float` in C. The data you are reducing is of type `double`, therefore you should use `MPI_DOUBLE` instead. The same applies to the MPI calls in the other parts of your program.

Comment: Huh, there i though it was the same. I was actually porting code from Fortran so that makes sense. Thx!